# Orchestration of javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, orchestration

I am attempting to run 2 functions and then re-locate a user in a click handler. The code is as follows.

```
$(".myLink").click( function() {
  function1(param1); // This function contains an ajax call that updates a DB.
  function2(param1); // This function does as well.
  window.location="foo.php";
});
```

While my window.location relocates properly, the functions are not firing correctly. I am stuck on jQuery 1.43 so I cannot use deferred objects.

What's the accepted architecture for dealing with the above orchestration.

Comment: `I am stuck on jQuery 1.4.3` _i feel sorry for you_. Use good old callbacks, then.

Answer (score 4):

Callbacks

```
$(".myLink").click( function() {
  function1(param1, { success: function() {
    function2(param1, { success: function() {
      window.location = "foo.php";
    }});
  }});
});
```

Or perhaps this, which would allow them to fire at the same time:

```
$(".myLink").click( function() {
  completed = 0;
  var success = function() {
    completed++;
    if (completed === 2) {
      window.location = "foo.php";
    }
  }
  function1(param1, { success: success });
  function2(param1, { success: success });
});
```

Which is basically how you might do it without a proper `Defered` library.

Comment: Yikes, I was hoping it wouldn't be this messy, but makes sense. Thanks for the quick response. Deferred objects are much more elegant!

Comment: `Deferred` was a concept that came around _precisely because_ of how messy this is.

Comment: @JasonWells Your functions need to be structured to handle a callback.  This structure is not magic. You haven't posted that code, so I can't advise more.

Answer (score 1):

Your `success` function for the first ajax call will have to trigger the 2nd ajax call.